# Where is the OpenCart form action url

Tags: forms, twig, opencart-3

I am using OpenCart 3.0.2.0. Where is the form action path in OpenCart Twig file?

Here is some of the code:

```
    <form action="{{ action }}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="form-product" class="form-horizontal">
```

I don't know where this action comes from.

Comment: If it is default oc piece of code, this url should be in corresponding controller file. In controller you should find something like this `$data['action'] = $this->url->link('some/path/to/your/file');`

Answer (score 0):

You can go to the admin directory

Path :

> admin\controller\catalog\product.php

and find

```
$data['action']
```

you can see it for action in view files as well.